# DRF: How to limit fields in nested serializer based on field-permissions?

Tags: django, serialization, django-rest-framework, permissions

I'm trying to limit the `fields` list in serializers based on user permissions.  I have a generic routine that does it for all serializers.  It's working on the parent serializer, but not on a nested serializer.

I have a client model, and a client profile (referred to as "contacts") as shown below.  The client profile model is an extension of the user model (one-to-one relationship).

```py
class Client(AddressPhoneModelMixin, DateFieldsModelMixin, models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    status = models.CharField(max_length=25)

    class Meta:
        permissions = (
            # Object-level
            ('view_all_clients', 'Can view all clients'),
            ('change_all_clients', 'Can change all clients'),
            # Field-level
            ('view_client_id', 'Can view client ID'),
            ('view_client_name', 'Can view client name'),
            ...others omitted...
        )
```

```py
class ClientProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(
        User,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        blank=True,
        null=True,
    )
    client = models.ForeignKey(
        Client,
        on_delete=models.PROTECT,
        related_name='contacts',
    )
    receive_invoices = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

My object-level permission logic is in the list view:

```py
class ClientList(ListAPIView):
    permission_classes = (IsAuthenticated,)
    serializer_class   = ClientSerializer

    def get_queryset(self):
        user     = self.request.user
        queryset = None

        if user.has_perm('view_client') or user.has_perm('clients.view_all_clients'):
            queryset = Client.objects.all().exclude(status__in=['deleted', 'archived'])

        if user.has_perm('view_client'):        # View only "assigned" clients
            if user.type == 'client':
                # See if user is a "contact".
                queryset = queryset.distinct().filter(contacts__user=self.request.user)
            else:
                # See if user is assigned to projects for the client(s).
                queryset = queryset.distinct().filter(projects__project_users__user=self.request.user)

        if queryset is None:
            raise PermissionDenied('You do not have permission to view clients.')
        return self.get_serializer_class().setup_eager_loading(queryset)
```

Removing fields from the serializer "fields" property is done in the serializer `__init__` method (from examples I found here in SO):

```py
class ClientContactsSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    url  = serializers.HyperlinkedIdentityField(view_name='clients:clientprofile-detail')
    user = UserSerializer()

    class Meta:
        model = ClientProfile
        fields = (
            'url',
            'receive_invoices',
            'user',
        )

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(ClientContactsSerializer, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        check_field_permissions(self, 'view')
```

```py
class ClientSerializer(AddressPhoneSerializerMixin, serializers.ModelSerializer):
    url      = serializers.HyperlinkedIdentityField(view_name='clients:client-detail')
    contacts = ClientContactsSerializer(many=True, read_only=True)
    projects = ClientProjectsSerializer(many=True, read_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Client
        fields = (
            'url',
            'id',
            'name',
            ...omitted for brevity...
            'contacts',
            'projects',
        )

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(ClientSerializer, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        check_field_permissions(self, 'view')

    @staticmethod
    def setup_eager_loading(queryset):
        queryset = queryset.select_related('country')
        return queryset.prefetch_related('contacts', 'contacts__user', 'contacts__user__country', 'projects')
```

And, finally, here's the check_field_permissions function:

```py
def check_field_permissions(serializer, action='view'):
    request = serializer.context.get('request', None)
    fields  = serializer.get_fields()
    model   = serializer.Meta.model

    app_name   = model._meta.app_label
    model_name = model._meta.model_name

    if request is not None and app_name is not None and model_name is not None:
        user = request.user

        for field_name in fields:
            if hasattr(serializer.fields[field_name], 'child'):
                continue
            if not user.has_perm(app_name + '.' + action + '_' + model_name + '_' + field_name):
                serializer.fields.pop(field_name)
```

Stepping through in debug on a page-load of the Client list, I can see that the above function is invoked first for clientprofile, and request is None.  The second time, it is invoked for client, and request is a valid request object.

First question, is `__init__` the correct place for limiting the list of fields to be serialized?

Second, how to get the request object in the nested serializer (clientprofile)?

Answer (score 1):

After reading a post by Tom Christie, who is an undisputed authority on DRF, I was able to solve my issue.  He pointed out that each nested serializer does, in fact, have the context object (and the request, and the user).  You just have to deal with nested serializers in the parent `__init__` - not their own `__init__`.

Here's my revised check_field_permissions() function:

```py
def check_field_permissions(serializer, action='view'):
    request = serializer.context.get('request', None)
    fields  = serializer.get_fields()
    model   = serializer.Meta.model

    app_name   = model._meta.app_label
    model_name = model._meta.model_name

    if request is not None and app_name is not None and model_name is not None:
        user         = request.user
        extra_fields = []

        for field_name in fields:
            if field_name == 'url':
                extra_fields.append(field_name)
                continue
            if hasattr(serializer.fields[field_name], 'child'):
                check_field_permissions(serializer.fields[field_name].child, action)
                extra_fields.append(field_name)
                continue
            if not user.has_perm(app_name + '.' + action + '_' + model_name + '_' + field_name):
                serializer.fields.pop(field_name)

        # If only "url" and child fields remain, remove all fields.
        if len(serializer.fields) == len(extra_fields):
            for field_name in extra_fields:
                serializer.fields.pop(field_name)
```

It is now recursive.  If it hits a field with a "child" attribute, it knows that's a nested serializer field.  It calls itself with that child serializer passed as an arg.

The other change is that `__init__` was removed from ClientContactsSerializer, because it doesn't need to call check_field_permissions().